# Page not displaying in browser through controller

Tags: java, html, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to get my jsp to show in the browser by accessing it through a controller, however I am getting a 404, with no error on the console.

I was just wondering if anyone can notice anything wrong with my files:

web.xml:

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>DefaultServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DefaultServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

DefaultServlet-servlet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.shaun.projectSOL" />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

HomeController:

```
package com.shaun.projectSOL;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView welcome() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("welcome");
        modelAndView.addObject("greeting", "Welcome to Web Store!");
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

welcome.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;
charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/
bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <div class="container">
                <h1>${greeting}</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try `modelAndView.addObject("welcome", "Welcome to Web Store!");`, rather than `greeting`.  The `modelAndView` gives Spring the name of your JSP to load. You want to load your `welcome.jsp`.

Comment: This isn't correct... add object stores the seconds string under the first one. for exmaple Welcome to Web Store will be stored under 'welcome' @MrSpoon

Comment: Oops-  yes you're right - sorry.